# How to format a String with spaces based on a specified length?

Tags: java, string

Trying to create a method in Java formats the string by stretching the content (by putting appropriate number of whitespaces) of a buffer, based on the length. So, based on a particular length given, the first character of the string is in the first index and the last character is located at the actual last index itself.

```
public static String format(String sentence, int length) {
    if (sentence.length() >= length) {
        return sentence;
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String[] words = sentence.split("\\s+");

    int usedCharacters = 0;

    for (String word : words) {
        usedCharacters += word.length();
    }

    int emptyCharacters = length - usedCharacters;
    int spaces = emptyCharacters / words.length - 1;

    for (String word : words) {
        sb.append(word);
        for (int i = 0; i <= spaces; i++) {
            sb.append(" ");
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

For this unit test, this works:

```
@Test
public void isCorrectLength() {
    String value = StringUtils.format("brown clown", 20);
    assert(value.length() == 20);
}
```

So, here, the maximum buffer size is: 20

Total number of used characters is: 10

Total number of unused characters is: 10

The end result (if you print the String) is:

```
brown     clown
```

The "n" in clown is at index 20...

However, there is an edge case with the following test (which causes it to break):

```
@Test
public void isCorrectLengthWithLongerSentence() {
    String value = StringUtils.format("Love programming Java using Eclipse!", 50);
    assert(value.length() == 50);
}
```

Buffer size: 50

Total Used Characters: 25
Total Unused Characters: 25

Spaces: 3

Final Length: 48

The end result (if you print the String) is:

```
Love     programming    Java    using    Eclipse!
```

Why is the final index 48 instead of 50?

The exclamation point "!" after "Eclipse", should be at 50 instead of 48...

Am suspecting that its due to my spaces calculation being off.

Thanks for taking the time to read this.

Comment: I'm guessing it's because you're using an int for your spaces calculation so rounding is becoming an issue. The spaces between words all can't be the same.

Comment: The problem is with `int spaces = emptyCharacters / words.length - 1;`. First off, I think you mean `emptyCharacters / (words.length - 1)`. Secondly, as @SamOrozco said, you'll need different numbers of spaces if it doesn't divide evenly...

Comment: I'm pretty sure this was on the AP Comp. Sci. exam last year :D

Comment: Just a thought, it might be an interesting exercise to try and do this with a variant of the Bresenham line algorithm, using (wordcount - 1) as delta y, and (availablepadding) as the delta x, to get a precise regular distribution of spaces. The algorithm essentially partitions a space of a given length into a repeating sequence of groups of length n and n+1.

Answer (score 2):

For this test

```
@Test
public void isCorrectLength() {
    String value = StringUtils.format("Went to the slope and snowboarded for hours., 103);
    assert(value.length() == 103);
}
```

This happens because you are dividing:

```
int spaces = emptyCharacters / words.length - 1;
```

This results in (66 / 8) - 1) = 7.25, and then you have a for loop, which does not account for the extra .25 This means you will not fill the desired buffer length.

Also, since you declared it as int, you will not get the extra 0.25, so you should change it to `double`, and cast the others as double as well.

You then can count the words and check if the extra 0.25 multiplied by the counter reaches 1, you add a space, and reset the counter.

```
    double spaces = (double)emptyCharacters / (double)words.length - 1.0;

    double extraSpace = spaces % 1;
    double counter = 0;
    for (String word : words) {
        counter++;

        sb.append(word);
        for (int i = 0; i <= spaces; i++) {
            sb.append(" ");
        }

        if ((counter * extraSpace) >= 1) {
             sb.append(" "); // This is the extra space.
             counter = 0;
        }
    }
```

Something like this. The problem resides in that not all words can have the same number of spaces. Some will have more, some will have less, in order to accommodate for the static buffer length. This is also a special case, because the remainder is 0.25, and will produce exactly 2 spaces, You still need to accommodate for the remainder of the remainder. (In case it does not reach 1 and you still have one more word.)

The following code makes up for this.

```
    double spaces = (double)emptyCharacters / (double)words.length - 1.0;

    double extraSpace = spaces % 1;
    double counter = 0;
    int wordIndex = 0;
    for (String word : words) {
        counter++;
        wordIndex++;

        sb.append(word);
        for (int i = 0; i <= spaces; i++) {
            sb.append(" ");
        }

        if ((counter * extraSpace) >= 1) {
             sb.append(" "); // This is the extra space.
             counter = 0;
        }

        if ((wordIndex == words.length - 1) && (counter * extraSpace) > 0) {
            sb.append(" "); // This accounts for remainder.
        }
    }
```

This is not, in any way, elegant, but it works, for the previous test, and for example, for this new one:

```
@Test
public void isCorrectLength() {
    String value = StringUtils.format("We went to the giant slope and snowboarded for hours., 103);
    assert(value.length() == 103);
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't use float for this, because float is not precise. Consider, for example, what happens if extraSpace = 0.3333. When you add three of them, it doesn't quitereach 1.

Comment: That is a good observation. Should we use double? Or maybe add some precision tolerance?

Comment: What you could do is use a float to count spaces, with fractions, as you go, and round each time to determine number of spaces to add. At the same time initialize an int with the number of available spaces and decrement the actual number of spaces you're adding as you go. Then for the very last group just use the remaining space count as your insert count, instead of the fractional accumulator you've been using. This should cover all cases and give a good even distribution with a precise total.

Comment: Jason C, thank for the response... Can you provide some code as an example?

Comment: Hi Basilio German, sorry, it still prints 101 with your code but not 103. Thanks for providing the code, nonetheless!

Comment: Yes, you should change spaces to `float`. in your code it is `int`. Also i updated the counter mechanism.

Comment: Don't use floating point at all. Use only int. Just use the average number of spaces between words except the last one, and a remainder (a different number of spaces) for the last gap.

Comment: Klitos Kyriacou, Thanks for the tip... Can you show me what you mean regarding the remainder?

Comment: Alright then, the code was meant as a helping point. You should have gotten the idea of what was happening. The `extraSpace` is the remainder, but it still was 0 because you needed to cast the numbers to double. Also, the if comparison needed to be `>=` instead of `>`. Didn't you notice? or debugged it? It is fixed now and tested, and prints 103 now.

Comment: Thanks Basilio German - found a different solution but I appreciate the help! Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, it also did not pass the test if you added 2 more words, with 103, but it is fixed now as well. I am a bit rusty on my Java, but glad i could help.

Answer (score 1):

1. Split the string into words, based on white space.
2. Find the number of total spaces needed to pad the words to the desired string length (total length of string - words length).
3. Find the number of "space blocks" to be placed between words (number of words - 1).
4. Build the "space blocks" by iteratively adding spaces to each space block until we run out of spaces (see step 2).
5. Re-assemble the sentence by placing word, space block, word, etc.

   private static String formatString(String sentence, int length) {
       // parse words by white space
       String[] words = sentence.split("\s+");

   ```
   // calc the char length of all words
   int wordsLength = 0;
   for (String w: words) {
       wordsLength += w.length();
   }

   // find the number of space blocks and initialize them
   int spacesLength = length - wordsLength;
   String[] spaceBlocks = new String[words.length - 1];
   Arrays.fill(spaceBlocks, "");

   // distribute spaces as evenly as possible between space blocks
   int spacesLeft = spacesLength;
   int k = 0;
   while (spacesLeft > 0) {
       spaceBlocks[k++] += " ";
       if (k == spaceBlocks.length) {
           k = 0;
       }
       spacesLeft--;
   }

   // assemble the buffer: for each word, print the word, then a spaces block, and so on
   StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
   for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
       b.append(words[i]);
       if (i < spaceBlocks.length) {
           b.append(spaceBlocks[i]);
       }
   }
   return b.toString();
   ```

   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       String s;
       String t;

   ```
   s = "Hello, spaces.";
   t = formatString(s, 50);
   System.out.println(String.format("\"%s\" (length=%d)", t, t.length()));

   s = "Hello, spaces.";
   t = formatString(s, 51);
   System.out.println(String.format("\"%s\" (length=%d)", t, t.length()));

   s = "Good day, spaces.";
   t = formatString(s, 52);
   System.out.println(String.format("\"%s\" (length=%d)", t, t.length()));

   s = "The quick brown fox.";
   t = formatString(s, 53);
   System.out.println(String.format("\"%s\" (length=%d)", t, t.length()));

   s = "Ask not what your country can do for you.";
   t = formatString(s, 54);
   System.out.println(String.format("\"%s\" (length=%d)", t, t.length()));

   s = "Ask not what your country can do for you, Bob.";
   t = formatString(s, 55);
   System.out.println(String.format("\"%s\" (length=%d)", t, t.length()));
   ```

   }

Output,

```
"Hello,                                     spaces." (length=50)
"Hello,                                      spaces." (length=51)
"Good                   day,                  spaces." (length=52)
"The            quick            brown            fox." (length=53)
"Ask   not   what   your   country   can  do  for  you." (length=54)
"Ask  not  what  your  country  can  do  for  you,  Bob." (length=55)
```

In the cases where the spaces don't result in all even-length space blocks, the code favors placing them in the earlier-occurring space blocks.

Note for clarity I did not code edge cases (one-word strings, zero-length output, null inputs, words don't fit in buffer, etc). That's left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: I give up trying to get SO to format this correctly. If someone else can fix it, thanks.